# Coding automatic reply buttons in ASP.NET email generated message

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, email

I am working on building a workflow application. My application automatically determines who an Approver should be based on business logic and generates an email to them with summary information requesting there approval.

I am trying to figure out how I can add an approval and reject button to the email, so that when the Approver clicks it automatically replies to the email with Approve or Reject in the body, and possibly appending it to the mail subject line.

Any help or links to resources on how to do something like this would be appreciated; I searched and searched and haven't come up with anything.

Comment: you can't. The closest you can do is make a button that will open a link

Comment: Would I code this in the code behind file of the webform page?

Comment: you are inside an email so you do that in email text